# Regexp Oracle remove everything after zip code of US and Canada format

Tags: regex, oracle, zipcode, regexp-replace

I have address formats which are like

> 123, abc street, Dallas, Tx 75701, 500-998-7898, Directions X Y Z west
>   of

I want to delete anything after the ZIP CODE that matches US format in either 5 digit format or 5 digit + 4 digit code format as well as Canadian postal code format like Y89 567 or Y89567.

So my final answer should look like.

> 123, abc street, Dallas, Tx 75701

Appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you "recognize" a zip code? Are you assuming that two letters (state code) followed by one space followed by five digits followed by non-alphanumeric character or end of string is always a zip code - ignoring for the moment the zip + 4 possibility?

Comment: Is the state/province with postal code always after the third comma?

Comment: Btw, your canadian postal codes do not match the documented format, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. Note that anything that "looks like" a U.S. or Canadian zip code will be assumed to be one. Also, you will miss things like `Beverly Hills, Calif. 90210` because "Calif." is not "seen" as a state code. I am also a bit careless; if there is anything after the zip code, it shouldn't be a letter or a digit. I didn't write the "test" for that; left as exercise, if needed.

I assume that if no zip code is found, the entire input string must be returned.

```
with
  inputs ( addr ) as (
    select '123, abc street, Dallas, Tx 75701, 500-998-7898'        from dual union all
    select '336 Main St, New City, NZ 39023-8882, john.d@email'     from dual union all
    select '837B Hilltop, Canadian City, ON Z34802 4028048 kilo'    from dual union all
    select '12345 Circle Drive, Lakeview, MN'                       from dual
  )
select addr,
       regexp_substr( addr, 
                      '(.*?([[:alpha:]]{2} \d{5}(-\d{4})?|[[:alpha:]]\d{2} ?\d{3}|$))',
                      1, 1, null, 1) as clean_addr
from   inputs
;

ADDR                                                CLEAN_ADDR                        
--------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
123, abc street, Dallas, Tx 75701, 500-998-7898     123, abc street, Dallas, Tx 75701
336 Main St, New City, NZ 39023-8882, john.d@email  336 Main St, New City, NZ 39023-8882
837B Hilltop, Canadian City, ON Z34802 4028048 kilo 837B Hilltop, Canadian City, ON Z34802
12345 Circle Drive, Lakeview, MN                    12345 Circle Drive, Lakeview, MN
```

Comment: Yes, if no zip code is found the entire string must still be returned. This regex works exactly like I wanted. Thank you.